# Saving application data and settings without a database

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making a C# Winforms pet project and I have a dilemma. I want users of my application to be able to create unlimited project that I'd represent with an icon and a label. Also, whenever a project is clicked on a new form opens to show them the project files in that project. The project files are just text based documents and new ones can be added infinitely to a project too.

My questions:

1. How do I create something like the Android listview/gridview that I define a layout and it repeats the layout infinitely to show the projects and how do I save these projects so that when the application is closed and opened again I can show the project files in the said listview. I don't want it to be a database.
2. How do I do the same but for the project files instead? Basically, how do I repeat layout(control) infinitely, save data and restore data on launch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I create something like the Android listview/gridview?

Use FlowLayoutPanel + UserControl to mimic a ListView.

> I don't want it to be a database.

Save to XML files with System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.

```
static void Main()
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyData));

    var saveData = new MyData() { Abc = 123 };
    using (var writeFile = File.OpenWrite("data.txt"))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writeFile, saveData);
    }

    using (var readFile = File.OpenRead("data.txt"))
    {
        var retrieveData = (MyData)serializer.Deserialize(readFile);
        Console.WriteLine(retrieveData.Abc);
    }
}

public class MyData
{
    public int Abc { get; set; }
}
```